# program crashes when press button - Number guess game - Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have no idea why this is not working, I have been looking and I cant see whats wrong I have messed with it for a while all I want is for it to work.
gets input outputs numbers equal to randomly generated if full number equals the random then you win but it just crashes when I press the button

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
master = Tk()
master.title('Guess The Number!')
global answer
global guess_entry
global guess_display
answer = str(random.randint(1000,9999))
guess_counter = 0
def callback():
    print('Button pressed')
    counter = 0

    correct = []
    while counter < 4:
        if guess_entry.get() == answer:
            correct.append('Well done, that is correct')
            break
        elif guess_entry.get()[counter] == answer[counter]:
            correct.append(guess_entry.get[counter])

            counter += 1
    guess_display['text'] = '  '.join(str(correct))

def Help():
    win = Toplevel()
    win.title('Help')

    l = Label(win, text="Guess a 4 digit number and I will tell you\n what you got right,\n keep trying until you get it in the \ncorrect order with correct numbers")
    l.grid(row=0, column=0)

    b = Button(win, text="Okay", command=win.destroy)
    b.grid(row=1, column=0)

guess_entry = Entry(master)

guess_check = Button(master, text='Guess', command=callback)

guess_display = Label(master,text='_  _  _  _')


help_button = ttk.Button(master, text="?", command=Help,width=3)

guess_entry.grid(row=0,column=2)
guess_check.grid(row=1,column=2)

guess_display.grid(row=2,column=1)

help_button.grid(row=0,column=4)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your while loop seems pointless. At no point during that loop does the user have an opportunity to enter any data. `guess_entry.get()` is going to return exactly the same thing every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @BryanOakley they dont need to enter anything its a check to see they numbers that are equal.

Comment: @BryanOakley Oakly and the guess_entry.get() i assume ou mean the `if guess_entry.get()== answer:`, that is to check if the entire number is correct not just some

Comment: I see two calls to `Tk()` in your code - that never ends well.  You need to use `Toplevel()` to create additional windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers aren't equal the first time through the loop, they won't be equal any other time through the loop since the user won't have a chance to change their answer while the loop is running.

You can see this by adding a print statement:

```
while counter < 4:
    print("counter:", counter, "guess:", guess_entry.get())
    ...
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now, but I still dont get why it is crashing

Comment: @Catmantj: it is "crashing" because the loop never, ever, ever exits.